# How do I migrate my Flutter project from vscode to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I created my Flutter project by typing into my CLI `Flutter create project_name` and all this time I've been coding using VScode, and the project is near completion, which means I have to do a software demo in the coming days to my professors in university. However, I would need to open multiple android emulators that will run the same project, based on my brief research and testing, VScode does not allow running multiple android emulators that run the same project. So I have to transfer that project from VScode to Android Studio.

I've tried simply opening my Flutter folder in Android Studio and I'm getting gradle build errors. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: its simple, just download android studio and install flutter plugin. It will let you restart the android studio, do it and then open your project folder in android studio

Comment: You should also post the Gradle errors that you are seeing (in addition to making sure AS/Flutter plugins are installed).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I've managed to fix it, turns out I had some problems in my android manifest due to a new package i added.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have the Flutter plugin installed in Android Studio, you can just open the folder like any other.

Though FWIW, I don't know if Android Studio supports debugging on multiple devices at the same time. It does work in VS Code (as shown at Flutter Interact with the "Flutter Octopus") if you're on the `master` channel (see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Multi-device-debugging-in-VS-Code).